# Opening gedit tabs

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I heavily use gedit for opening and editing documents. Since yesterday (with no update or upgrade), gedit has started to open each document as a new window instead of its default behavior to open as a new tab.

How can I revert the behavior to open each document as a new tab.

Comment: if I don't catch it wrong, your mean use `gedit --new-document 1.txt 2.txt` that's automatically opened as two tabs in one window.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri When I open on the desktop, not command line. When I open the second document, it opens as a new window as that a new tap of the already opened window.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this essential information.

Comment: Post the output of `cat /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop | grep Exec -B3`